# How to Purge CQ Audit Log of Pages

Tags: aem, audit-logging

The only reference I found online regarding purging audit log of CQ pages is [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/howtopurgewf.html). However, it is not clear as to how do I go about doing it. Say .... purge audit log that are older than 60 days of pages in my repository. The audit logs are stored under:

> /var/audit/com.day.cq.wcm.core.page/

Is there a way to purge audit log via the Web Console?

Comment: Try creating a JMX script, you can go to web console and see JMX in menu options. See this http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/jmx-integration.html Answering assuming that you want to delete only through web console. There are many other ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

See http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/howtopurgewf.html

Install the package "Workflow n Audit purge-1.7.5.zip" which will expose a configuration entry in the Web Console (/system/sonsole/configMgr) named "Audit Purge Watch Service".  You can use this to schedule regular audit event purges.

For one-time audit event purge, navigate to /etc/versioning/purge.html